# How to subset only university names from a string with other variables

Tags: python

I am having issue with getting only the university names in a string partial look as below:

```
Rank    Name
Country/Region
1   University of Oxford
United Kingdom
2   California Institute of Technology
United States
3   University of Cambridge
United Kingdom
4   Stanford University
United States
5   Massachusetts Institute of Technology
United States
6   Princeton University
United States
7   Harvard University
United States
8   Yale University
United States
```

What I want is a list of only university names.
tried to use re.sub but cannot decide on the pattern.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You just need to find which lines have a digit as their first character. You should show what you've tried/researched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your data is actually formatted, but if it's formatted like you posted here with a `\n` newline character at the end of each line and there are exactly always three spaces between the numbers and the university name, this would iterate over each line:

```
t = "whatever your text is"

for i in t.split("\n"):
   if i[0].isdigit():
      print(" ".join(i.split(" ")[3:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex:

```
^\d +(.*)
```

and grab the contents of group 1 for each match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern :

```py
^\d+\s+(.*)
```